# Can node-canvas use in NextJs application?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm using NextJs (SSR) and need to use node-canvas to create images. Everytime I called canvas.someFunction(), an error like TypeError: canvas.someFunction is not a function appears.

For example,

```
TypeError: canvas.createPNGStream is not a function.
```

So, I'm wondering if node-canvas can be used with NextJs or not.

If can't, is there any alternative that can be used?

Edit: Here is my codes

```
useEffect(() => {
const { width, height } = details.dimension;
const canvas = createCanvas(width, height);
const image = await loadImage(imageURL);
ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height);
const png = canvas.createPNGStream()
});

// Note: I tried using canvas.toBuffer('image/png') and it has the same TypeError.
```

Comment: Where in your code are you trying to use `node-canvas`? Could you provide a [mre]?

Comment: Sorry for not providing the code since I thought the problem is mainly about SSR. I've edited the question, please take a look at it :)

Comment: how do you import node-canvas?

Comment: import { createCanvas} from "canvas";

Comment: Can you provide more details around that code? Where do you end up using that piece of code? Is that in a helper function that's used somewhere else?

Comment: It is wrapped in an useEffect

Comment: `node-canvas` is a Node.js library meant to be used on the server-side, it cannot be used on the client-side (browser). Use the [Canvas API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API) available to you in the browser instead.